# How does Apache Drill work on top of Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-drill

How does Apache Drill work on top of Hive? Does it execute MapReduce to query, or is it something like how Tez works? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. The storage plugin integrates Drill with Hive metadata. Drill does not invoke the Hive execution engine for any
requests as stated in the [Drill docs](http://drill.apache.org/docs/core-modules). You can use Drill to read Hive data, not to write. The [Hive Storage Plugin section](http://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/) has more info.